# CSS related, content floating upward (on top of header image) only on FireFox...

Tags: css, layout

http://ratest3.com/spare-2/

The main content area is floating up over the header image only in FireFox.  I've checked it in the latest-greatest of Safari, Chrome, IE and on my Galaxy S3.

Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `clear: right;` to the `#main` CSS declaration. That fixed it for me in Firefox.

Alternatively, you could probably apply a clearfix class to the `#branding` div. (I didn't try that though.)

Comment: Ahhhhh... isn't it funny how Fire Fox just said "nope..."  I had done the clear and just was curious if I had dome something 'wrong'.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: Great! You have the honor of being my first accepted answer (if you so choose.)